# How are these components called?

Tags: structures

I need to build a structure like the one in the picture below. Basically, it is a pendulum that holds a measurement hammer and lets it oscillate without friction. I don't know how to find the two necessary components (the one that holds the hammer and the one that is fixed on the shaft). How are they called?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the entire assembly? A subassembly? One part? It isn't clear from the image what you want named. Part of this may be because certain components are visually overlapping. (The image is appreciated, but may be insufficient to answer the question.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few identifiable things in the picture

- The large P shaped object would be called a 'bearing housing', this looks like it may have been custom manufactured for this application, it is certainly not  a very common component although it is broadly similar to a [pillow block](http://www.bestbearingsonline.co.uk/np1116--ucwp203-11-budget-two-bolt-cast-iron-1116-borelummer-illow-block-housed-unit-with-grub-screw-5321.html) which are readily available. The one in the example is probably machined from billet of steel or aluminium (possibly based on some other component but I'm not sure what).
- the o shaped component holding the horizontal shaft is a [needle roller bearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_roller_bearing). This class of bearing has the rolling elements bearing directly onto the shaft they support rather than having an inner shell.
- The horizontal shaft is probably [silver steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_steel) or similar, this is convenient for shafts fitted to bearings as it is available precision ground to standard sizes and has good wear and mechanical properties.

This would be a fairy simple job for any machine shop as the important operations are just drilling and tapping holes. Machining the P shape is a bit more involved but that is not strictly necessary for the basic functionality. at  a push you could do it with a pillar drill and a hacksaw.